# Android to PHP JSON returns null

Tags: php, android, json

Below is my Java code to send to PHP:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String id){
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        String response = null;
        //JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        try{

                URL urlPost = new URL(url);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlPost.openConnection();
                //set request properties
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); //defaults request method to POST
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);  //allow input to this HttpURLConnection
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //header params
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); //header params
                httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(id.getBytes().length); //header param "content-length"
                //open output stream and POST our JSON data to server
                outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                outputStreamWriter.write(id);
            Log.e(TAG,"HttpHandler's id is: " + id);
                outputStreamWriter.flush(); //flush the stream when we're finished writing to make sure all bytes get to their destination
                //read the response
                //prepare input buffer and get the http response from server
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                //read in each line of the response to the input buffer
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close(); //close out the input stream

                try {
                    //Copy the JSON response to a local JSONObject
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    je.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'connecttodb.php';

    $db = new DB();
    $con = $db->db_connect();

    //check for required fields
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM warehouse_sales WHERE id='$id'";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $result = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
            array_push($result,["id"=>$row[0],"company_name"=>$row[1],"promotion_image"=>$row[2],
            "title"=>$row[3],"promotional_period"=>$row[4],"expiry_date"=>$row[5],
            "sales_description"=>$row[6],"sales_location"=>$row[7]]);
        }
        echo json_encode(array("Result"=>$result));
        $db->db_close();
    }
?>
```

I am trying to pass an `id` from Android to PHP and it will return a JSON result based on the id. I am pretty sure that the values of url and id got passed into the method but the JSON result returns `null` instead as shown in the logcat.

Comment: It is returning with 200 OK? Also if anything causes an error in your code then it'll output it by default right there so it could be something:
[Warning] ....
your JSON goes here

Comment: 1. Add some logging in your PHP script to verify everything is set and the query has results. 2. You are vulnerable to SQL injection this way, please parameterize your query properly.

Comment: @Robert how should I log the php script ?

Comment: Either use syslog, a logger package or for now simply echo the output of what you need to know. (instead of valid json output you'll return the debug data)

Answer (score 0):

A) Clean any $_POST variable before sending to MySQL : $id = $db->real_escape_string($city); $_POST['id'];

B) turn off error ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

C) Handle Errors: use TRY before spitting anything in JSON

D) You don't show the part "Result"=>ID is being loaded, maybe there is a typo in 'result' instead of "Result"

```
<?php 
    require_once 'connecttodb.php';

    $db = new DB();
    $con = $db->db_connect();

    //check for required fields
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM warehouse_sales WHERE id='$id'";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $result = array();

        try {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                array_push($result,["id"=>$row[0],"company_name"=>$row[1],"promotion_image"=>$row[2],
                "title"=>$row[3],"promotional_period"=>$row[4],"expiry_date"=>$row[5],
                "sales_description"=>$row[6],"sales_location"=>$row[7]]);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        if (isset($error_message))
            echo json_encode(array("Error"=>$error_message));
        else
            echo json_encode(array("Result"=>$result));

        $db->db_close();
    }
?>
```

E) Use a simple code like below to find if your PHP or Java code is fauly:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("Result"=>123));
?>
```

Comment: the latest error org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0

Answer (score 0):

I m not used to with Android but I think issue here is you are passing Post variable id, but u specifically telling server that data you are sending is json format.

I would say best way is too use "php://input" to accept input then json_decode on php script.

Comment: im sending plaintext

Comment: It will help if u provide what is plain text you r passing for example. Also I can check ur passed variables by directly echo them n exit from php script. First thing first, confirm u pass variable correctly rest will follow.